# Finding $P_{\theta}(X_1 + X_2 > X_3)$ when $X_1, X_2, X_3 \stackrel{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} Bernoulli(\theta)$

Tags: probability

I know that $P_{\theta}(X_1 + X_2 > X_3) = 1 - P_{\theta}(X_1 + X_2 < X_3),$ but how do I find $P_{\theta}(X_1 + X_2 < X_3)$ when the right hand side of the inequality is a random variable?

Comment: In general, you can move the random variable on the right to the left hand side, and then find another random variable such that it is equivalent in distribution to the combination of three random variables that you'll have on the left hand side. Then calculate the probability this random variable is $<0$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, they all are Bernoulli, so they take value in $\{0,1\}$. For us, that means $X_1+X_2 > X_3$ if, and only if,

- $X_3 = 1$ and $X_1=X_2=1$; *or*
- $X_3=0$ and not both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are $0$.

Since they are all independent, we have
$$
\mathbb{P}\{X_3 = 1,  X_1=X_2=1\}
= \mathbb{P}\{X_3 = 1\}\cdot\mathbb{P}\{X_1=1\}\cdot\mathbb{P}\{X_2=1\}
= \theta^3
$$
and
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\{X_3 = 0,  X_1+X_2\geq 1\}
&= \mathbb{P}\{X_3 = 0\}\cdot(1-\mathbb{P}\{X_1=X_2=0\})\\
&= \mathbb{P}\{X_3 = 0\}\cdot(1-\mathbb{P}\{X_1=0\}\mathbb{P}\{X_2=0\})\\
&= (1-\theta)\cdot(1-(1-\theta)^2)
\end{align*}$$
and therefore, since both events are disjoint,
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\{X_1+X_2> X_3\}  &= \mathbb{P}\{X_3 = 1,  X_1=X_2=1\} + \mathbb{P}\{X_3 = 0,  X_1+X_2\geq 1\}\\
&= \boxed{\theta^3 + (1-\theta)\cdot(1-(1-\theta)^2)}
\end{align*}$$
which you may then simplify a bit if you want.

Comment: Don't we also have $X_3=0$ and $X_1=X_2=1$ or did you include this part?

Comment: It's included in the second. If they are both 1, then in particular "they are not both 0”, @StubbornAtom. But you are right, I wrote the wrong expression for that somewhere after (just an which should be a $\geq$)

Comment: Fixed (that was literally changing two characters, and doesn't affect the result nor derivation). Thanks, @StubbornAtom, for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

For Bernoulli I would write out all the possibilities (there's 8 of them) and from there conclude the probability is equal to $\theta^2 + 2\theta(1-\theta)^2$. For other distrubutions and in general, Slades comment is the better approach.